# Differences between i7 2600 and i7 2600K

Tags: cpu, gpu, intel-core-i7

I looked at their specifications on intel.

It seems i7 2600K has HD Graphics 3000 while the i7 2600 has HD Graphic 2000. But other than that, the i7 2600 has several options and features that the i7 2600K lack.

How is it possible that the 2600K loses on intel's website and supasses the 2600 in a benchmark test?

http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary marketing difference between these two chips is that the 2600 is frequency locked and cannot be overclocked, while the 2600K (and all other -K proces in the current lineup) can be overclocked quite aggressively.

Comment: Oh, alright. So I should go with the 2600K and OC it.

Answer (score 6):

The `K` versions of the processors have unlocked multipliers, which means they can be overclocked. However, the `K` versions also lack some features, such as the virtualization extensions. I myself am confused as to why Intel removed features in their top-of-the-line processor that lower-end models include. The unlocked multipliers will explain the performance difference-- the i7-2600's are 3.4Ghz processors running at 3.4GHz, while the i7-2600K's are 3.4GHZ processors which are often performing in excess of 4.5GHz when they're being benchmarked. The speeds on the page you linked are simply stock speeds, and do not reflect the speed of the processor when the benchmark is being run.

Comment: I wonder if some of those disable functions are less stable when the core is overclocked?

Comment: It's entirely possible, though I wish that they include both and let the user choose instead of moving the differences into an entirely different processor.

Comment: I hadn't seen the differences besides the clock multiplier lock. This is the first I'd heard of the other differences. Looking through them now, most of the disabled bits appear to be specifically useful for corporate environments, which are probably never going to overclock their systems. Not many power users I know will run the XEN framework on any system, let along an overclocked one.